# Redirecting back to the correct location when action is called from multiple locations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails app which needs to update a certain object from multiple locations. After these updates, the controller responsible for this update should always redirect back to the location where one came from.

This works great with `redirect_to :back`, except in the case where I am coming from the standard `edit` action. Then of course it directs me back to the edit form, where normally I would like to have the standard Rails way to direct to the `show` action.

Is the solution to pass a parameter where to redirect to after a successful update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `redirect_to :back` is redirecting to the link contained in the HTTP header "HTTP_REFERER" (contained in the `request` variable which is a ActionDispatch::Request object).

You could test what contains this referer and behave differently for some value(s):

```
def update
  @object = MyObject.find(params[:id])
  # etc...

  if request.env['HTTP_REFERER'].present? 
    if request.env['HTTP_REFERER'].include?('/some/path/to/edit/')
      redirect_to object_path(@object)
    else
      redirect_to :back
    end
  else
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

Comment: You might want to extract this logic from the controller into a helper.